# What is Belgium's position on Catalonia declaration of independence?

Tags: secession, catalonia, belgium

According to [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/oct/01/catalan-referendum-eu-leaders-remain-muted-over-police-crackdown):

> **Belgium’s prime minister**, Charles Michel, **was among the few national leaders** to denounce the violence, which the Catalan
>   government said had left 465 people injured as police forcibly removed
>   voters from polling stations and on one occasion fired rubber bullets.

According to [Politico](https://www.politico.eu/article/how-the-world-reacted-to-catalan-independence-declaration/):

> **Belgian Prime Minister Charles Michel,** who was reportedly reprimanded
>   by the Spanish government for **not sticking to the EU’s line on the
>   crisis**, wrote: “A political crisis can only be solved through
>   dialogue. We call for a peaceful solution with respect for national
>   and international order.

According to Reuters, Belgium can theoretically grant political asylum to Carles Puigdemont:

> Granting Catalan leader Carles Puigdemont political asylum in Belgium
>   would be “not unrealistic” if he asks for it, the Belgian migration
>   minister said, underlining his country’s position as a contrarian
>   voice in the Spanish standoff.

It looks as if Belgium is quite sympathetic with Catalonia, contrary to [EU mainstream](http://www.express.co.uk/news/world/872401/Catalonia-latest-EU-international-recognition).

**Question:** What is Belgium's position on Catalonia declaration of independence? If it is different from main EU countries position (Germany, France, UK), what is the purpose?

Comment: I would highlight two things here: first, on extradition cases like this one, Belgium is known for checking thoroughly the reasons of the case, so Puigdemont would only be extradited after a serious judicial investigation on whether Spain is right or not to ask for it. Second, Belgian government is a mix of parties, some of them being Flemish independentist. Since these tend to support Catalonia's attempts for independence, it is likely that Charles Michel wouldn't criticize it much, not to anger one of his partners.